# Weighted survey functions by group

Tags: r

I have a weighted survey dataset that involves age groups, incomes and expenditure. I want to find the average of spending within age groups and within income deciles.

So for example

```
DF:
Age   Income     Spending1 Spending2  Weight 
45-49 1000       50        35          100
30-39 2000       40        60          150
40-44 3434       30        55          120
```

Currently I have coded this:

```
  DF$hhdecile<-weighted_ntile(DF$Income, weights=DF$Weight, 5)

  Result1<- DF %>% group_by(Age,hhdecile) %>% dplyr::summarise(mean.exp = weighted.mean(x = Spending1, w = Weight))

  Result2<- DF %>% group_by(Age,hhdecile) %>% dplyr::summarise(mean.exp = weighted.mean(x = Spending2, w = Weight))



df.list <- list(Result1=Result1,
                Result2=Result2)

names(df.list$Result1)[names(df.list$Result1)=="mean.exp"]<- Result1

ResultJoined < - df.list %>% reduce(full_join, by=c('Age','hhdecile')
```

That finds the quintile of people compared to the population of all ages, and I'm interested in their quintile compared to their age group.

Is there a way to use group_by or similar to perform the weighted percentile function on each age group individually?

(there are actually 15 categories of spending)

Comment: Have you considered using the survey package?

Comment: Second the recommendation for `survey`. There are also several functions for handling weights in descriptive stats in the `Hmisc` package, such as `wtd.quantile`. Where does `weighted_ntile` come from?

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/grattan/versions/1.6.0.0/topics/weighted_ntile

The nice thing about this function is that it returns the quintile category of every row in the DF, and you can then find the mean within that quintile. With wtd.qunatile you just get  the individual percentile. Can you use other random functions (like weighted_ntile) within the survey package?